# from online web site, javascript popup window doesnot work in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, iphone, uiwebview, window.open

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Opening popup links in UIWebView, possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245224/opening-popup-links-in-uiwebview-possible)

I stuck on one problem,
When i try to launch a page from live site to UIWebview in iphone, in that page it is opening one window using javascript (window.open).
I am not able to view this new popup window in UIWebview.
Can anyone help me to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ReedOlsen, I have not ask directly without looking this link, i have gone through this but didn't get result. Thanks for your precious time.

Comment: @ReedOlsen, i have already rewrite Ken answer in that question if you have not seen.