# how to open external link from webview in popup window ios

Tags: ios, uiwebview, popupwindow

I have embedded a webview in the view that loads a website. Now, I need to open external links inside webview in popup window.

Can anybody help me.

Thank you.

Comment: you mean you have to create a popup inside a UIWebview..

Comment: @BalaChandra: yes...I want a popup inside the webview.

Comment: Then you have to write the code for that in html..refer to the link provided in the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open popup's inside the UIWebview html rewriting is the best option.. write your html code in a file and load it in the webview

refer to the question for details..
[Opening popup links in UIWebView, possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245224/opening-popup-links-in-uiwebview-possible)